# giving goals with actionlib - in hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, actionlib, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the action lib tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) with stage (default simulation) and gazebo (pr2, `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch`). I am expecting the robot to move to the goal point, in both stage and gazebo the message I am getting is;

```
[ INFO] [1407054689.721298051]: Waiting for the move_base action server to come up
```

The corresponding tutorial(s) for which it was written are obsolete for hydro, any suggestions here would be helpful !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188724/giving-goals-with-actionlib---in-hydro/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-03**:
"nothing seems to work" is pretty vague. Can you pick one simulation (stage or gazebo) and describe exactly which commands you're running, what you expect, and what actually happens?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-08-03**:
@ahendrix - updated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 simulation launch file only launches the simulation of the robot - it doesn't launch any of the nodes required for navigation. I suspect stage is similar, but I haven't used it, so I can't say for sure.

If you want to run navigation on a simulated PR2, you'll need to install the PR2 navigation packages from source and run them alongside the simulation. The PR2 has not been fully ported to Hydro yet, so there may be some pieces missing here.

You're probably better off trying to use something like [navigation_stage](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation_stage), which appears to be packaged for Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1